# chart.js: One of the yAxis is not scaling properly in mixed chart

Tags: chart.js

Can someone please tell my why the bar chart data is not scaling correctly on the yAxis on the left?

It took me forever to get the two yAxis to even show and when I finally did, the yAxis for the bar chart went haywire.

```
<pre>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderColor = 'rgba(0, 29, 92, 1)';
    Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.backgroundColor = 'rgba(200, 218, 232, 1)';

    Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderWidth = '1';
    Chart.defaults.global.elements.rectangle.borderSkipped = 'bottom';
    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#666';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'normal';

    var chartData = {
        labels: ['2017-08-01', '2017-08-02', '2017-08-03', '2017-08-04', '2017-08-05', '2017-08-06', '2017-08-07', '2017-08-08', '2017-08-09', '2017-08-10', '2017-08-11', '2017-08-12', '2017-08-13', '2017-08-14', '2017-08-15', '2017-08-16', '2017-08-17', '2017-08-18', '2017-08-19', '2017-08-20', '2017-08-21', '2017-08-22', '2017-08-23', '2017-08-24', '2017-08-25', '2017-08-26', '2017-08-27', '2017-08-28', '2017-08-29', '2017-08-30', '2017-08-31'],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: 'High Temps',
            id: "line-axis",
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "yellow",
            borderColor: "red", // The main line color
            borderCapStyle: 'square',
            borderDash: [], // try [5, 15] for instance
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "black",
            pointBackgroundColor: "yellow",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 8,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "yellow",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "black",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [75, 77, 77, 80, 88, 85, 80, 90, 92, 97, 90, 98, 95, 90, 97, 93, 95, 85, 90, 92, 90, 95, 97, 99, 99, 96, 94, 94, 90, 92, 92]
        },
        {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Low Temps',
            fill: false,
            lineTension: 0.1,
            backgroundColor: "white",
            borderColor: "blue", // The main line color
            borderCapStyle: 'butt',
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
            pointBorderColor: "blue",
            pointBackgroundColor: "white",
            pointBorderWidth: 1,
            pointHoverRadius: 8,
            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "white",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "blue",
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
            pointRadius: 4,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            data: [65, 66, 66, 60, 62, 58, 60, 65, 68, 69, 70, 68, 65, 60, 67, 63, 65, 60, 60, 62, 65, 68, 61, 65, 65, 67, 64, 64, 60, 62, 62],
            borderWidth: 2
        },
        {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'Kilowatt Hours',
            id: 'bar-axis',
            type: 'linear',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 218, 232, 1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0, 29, 92, 1)',
            data: [75, 70, 77, 80, 88, 85, 80, 77, 70, 77, 80, 88, 85, 70, 77, 80, 88, 85, 70, 77, 80, 88, 85, 70, 77, 80, 88, 85, 70, 77, 80]
        }]

    };


    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: chartData,
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                        yAxes: [{
                            position: "right",
                            id: "line-axis",
                            scaleLabel: {
                                labelString: "Temperature",
                                display: "true"
                            }

                        },
                        {
                            position: "left",
                            id: "bar-axis",
                            scaleLabel: {
                                labelString: "Kilowatt Hours",
                                display: "true"
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                            }

                        }]
                },
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Kilowatt Hours Delivered'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: true
                }
            }
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(
    function () {

        $("#canvas").click(
            function (evt) {
                var activePoints = myMixedChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt)
                if (activePoints.length > 0)  // prevents error with clicking somewhere in the chart other than on a data segment
                {
                    var firstPoint = activePoints[0];
                    var label = myMixedChart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
                    var value = myMixedChart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
                    var url = "http://example.com/?label=" + label + "&value=" + value;
                    alert(url);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
</script>
</pre>
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what display you're getting with an explanation of what is wrong, graphically speaking?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Hey guys, I finally got it.  The problem was the use of "id:" in the dataset definition.  I should have used "yAxisID" instead.

Comment: Hey guys, I appreciate you guys looking at my problem so quickly.  I also appreciate the advice on a better way to post my question.  This was my first post.  I'll try and do better the next time.